# How to align TextInput and SelectInput

Tags: admin-on-rest

I want to put a TextInput and a SelectInput in the same line. However it not align good.inline-block

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a certain amount of idiosyncrasy in how these Material UI components are structured. To pass style related props to underlying component use the elStyle property and customize the css values being given till they align.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{
 height:40px;
 width:200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<input class="test">
<select class="test">
 <option>Test1</option>
 <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```